# PHPUnit database test: integer data type is returned as string

Tags: php, database, phpunit

This is my test which is not working as expected. My test class extends *PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase* and before each test run all tables are truncated and filled with the dataset shown below.

```
class NumberMapperTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase {

    private $dsn = 'mysql:host=...;dbname=test;port=3306;charset=utf8';
    private $conn = null;

    private $numberMapper;

    protected function getConnection() {
        if ($this->conn === null) {
            $pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, '...', '...');
            $this->conn = $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, 'test');
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function getDataSet() {
        $compositeDs = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_CompositeDataSet(array());
        $ds = $this->createMySQLXMLDataSet('fixtures/number.xml');
        $compositeDs->addDataSet($ds);
        return $compositeDs;
    }

    public function setUp() {
        $conn = $this->getConnection();
        $pdo = $conn->getConnection();

        $pdo->exec('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
        parent::setUp();
        $pdo->exec('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');

        $databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter($pdo);
        $this->numberMapper = new NumberMapper($databaseAdapter);
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        $conn = $this->getConnection();
        $pdo = $conn->getConnection();

        $pdo->exec('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
        parent::tearDown();
        $pdo->exec('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
    }

    protected function getTearDownOperation() {
        return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Factory::TRUNCATE();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     * @covers Classes\Mapper\NumberMapper::findByUid
     */
    public function findByUidReturnsExpectedNumber() {
        $expectedNumber = new Number(1, 'AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA');
        $this->assertEquals($expectedNumber, $this->numberMapper->findByUid('AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA'));
    }
}
```

The test throws the following exception:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The number ['1'] is invalid.
```

As you can see on the '' (quotes) the number is returned as string and not as number and I don't know why. Because it's stored as a number in the test database. I can confirm that with not truncating the table after my test run and use a small script to connect to my test database and run it. And everything works as expected - a Number object is created.

```
<?php
...
    $adapter = new DatabaseAdapter($pdo);
    $numberMapper = new NumberMapper($adapter);
    var_dump($numberMapper->findByUid('AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA'));
```

So my code seems to work correctly but my test fails (throws an exception). I've found no way to specify the data type for a column in my test dataset. Maybe there is the problem because it looks like all values are treated as string. But as said the number gets stored correctly as number into the database. Can someone explain what the reason for this behavior is, because I'm clueless.

My test database has a number table with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `number` (
    `uid` CHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `number` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `number` (`number`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

To test my NumberMapper with PHPUnit I used following data set [fixtures/number.xml]:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="test">
    <table_data name="number">
        <row>
            <field name="uid">AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA</field>
            <field name="number">1</field>
        </row>
    </table_data>
</database>
</mysqldump>
```

The NumberMapper which I want to test:

```
class NumberMapper {

    private $adapter;

    public function __construct($adapter) {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }

    public function findByUid($uid) {
        $this->adapter
             ->select(array('uid', 'number'))
             ->from('number')
             ->where('uid = :uid')
             ->bindParameters(array(':uid' => $uid));
        return $this->createEntity($this->adapter->fetch());
    }

    public function createEntity(array $data) {
        if (isset($data['number'])) {
            $uid = isset($data['uid']) ? $data['uid'] : $this->generateUid();
            return new Number($data['number'], $uid);
        } else {
            return new NullNumber();
        }
    }
}
```

My Number Domain Model looks like this:

```
class Number {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $uid;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $number;

    public function __construct($number, $uid) {
        $this->setUid($uid);
        $this->setNumber($number);
    }

    public function setUid($uid) {
        if (!is_string($uid) || strlen($uid) !== 36) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('The uid [' . var_export($uid, TRUE) . '] is invalid.');
        }
        $this->uid = $uid;
    }

    public function setNumber($number) {
        if (is_numeric($number) && !is_string($number) && 0 <= $number && $number <= 4294967295 === FALSE) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('The number [' . var_export($number, TRUE) . '] is invalid.');
        }
        $this->number = $number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem even so I still don't rely know why I have to do it this way. I noticed that there is indeed a difference in my small script and the test code. In my script I had some PDO attributes set which I was missing to also set in my test. The *PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES* attribute is the important one. Once I set this to false in my test everything worked as expected. I also set the *ATTR_ERRMODE* in my test now so that my getConnection method looks like this now:

```
protected function getConnection() {
    if ($this->conn === null) {
        $pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, '...', '...');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $this->conn = $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, 'test');
    }

    return $this->conn;
}
```